# Can I connect a PSU to the Ramps 1.6+ and the USB to Arduino at the same time?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, usb, ground-loop

I just want to connect the Ramps to the power supply unit and upload the Marlin firmware to the Arduino. I found three possible outcomes

### 1. Problem

I found one person [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/5772/20470) who says that we should not use external power for the Ramps and plug the USB to the Arduino at the same time because the board could burn:

> I was constantly hooking & unhooking my Arduino from my PC while the printer was plugged into the mains. At some point, it had enough & it released some "magic smoke". Later on, I found out this was the power regulator on the Arduino.
>
> You shouldn't need to plug in the USB and the external power to the Arduino at the same time, but if you did, it is smart enough to only use one.
>
> That being said, by default the RAMPS passes 5V straight to the Arduino to power it (using the Vin pin).

But the person who had asked the question wrote a new comment to this answer:

> I fixed the problem. Actually the diode D1 was creating that problem. I removed the diode D1 and now everything is working well.

I have [read](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/236262/244908) that the diode D1 (they may different boards, but I assume that the function of the diode is the same):

> According to the schematics of the board, there is a diode (D1) between the VDD5V and the VDDUSB net to prevent any current flowing back, towards the laptop's USB port.

If the other guy removed the diode could damage his laptop, right?

### 2. No problem if I take care of the grounds and rest of connections

An Electric Engineer also said in the comments of the same question

> As an EE, there is no specific problem with what you tried, provided that **all supplies are properly isolated**. Before burning another Arduino, reconnect the parts you have now one at a time, check for unexpected voltages. In particular, check that the ground levels are at zero or near-zero potential difference before connecting. Also, be sure that all grounds are tied together. The motor supply ground must be connected to logic ground. Grounding is a large subject, and someone will justifiably pile onto this answer with concerns about ground loops and noise, but if your grounds are not common, you risk sneak paths and destructive voltages when you interconnect systems.

I am a little confused about this. The ground in the PSU is clear (I use 12V and 15A):

[image: psu]

But where is the ground if I connect the Arduino by USB? Is my laptop adapter ground?

### 3. No problem at all

Finally [I found a video](https://youtu.be/izedBx5nCCM?t=885) where one guy connect both things at the same time. I think that's the only way to make the Pronterface work and move the motors directly or send some G-code instruction in the command line.

[image: pronterface]

### Socket

I have this kind of socket in my house, they just have Single Line (brown cable) and Neutral line (blue). So I wondering what happens if I don't have ground and if this could make burn some board.

[image: socket]

### Question

So my question is. Is it so common to burn the Arduino connecting both (PSU and USB)? Or the guy of the first question is just an exception? Should I worry about that? Do I need to do anything with the diode D1?

### Update

@Russell McMahon says I should connect all the grounds (negative terminals) together, from USB the supply and the PSU.

So I would like to know if instead of breaking the USB cable I could use any of the grounds that appear in the Ramps shield. I show here its diagram, as you can see there are many of them:

[image]

In the past, I have used Arduino and an external power supply and I could use the GND pin in the Arduino, that's why I am asking.

Comment: - Connect all grounds. || USB "ground" is the -ve of the 5V USB output. || This is why the EE said all supplies needed to be isolated - He meant isolated BEFORE you join their grounds together - if all supplies are not connected internally to any other point then connecting the USB -ve to the other grounds will be safe.

Comment: Thanks @RussellMcMahon. I have added a new complication. I think my sockets do not have any ground !

Comment: I should have been clearer. "Ground" is a convenient term for a common reference point. In this case it is the -ve line of the USB %V supply and the negative terminal of any other DC supplies that provide +ve voltages to the system. Connect these together.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I see. So, you mean I must extract the GND cable from [the USB](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FcQS-6QVUKKw%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&f=1&nofb=1) in order to connect both GNDs, PSU COM port and USB GND. I understand now. I am wondering if I can use some of the GNDs pins in the RAMPS board

Comment: I hace updated my question with the Ramps diagram to show all the possible GND pins I could use

Comment: When I "All grounds should be connected" does NOT means that there should be many ground traces from all points at ground potential BUT does mean that all ground points should be on a common "net" - ie all connected electrically at 0 Ohms if Cu had no resistance.
So eg The  -ve of USB 5v, / the negative of any other power supply, / the -ve of the RAMPS board, / the -ve of anything else that has +ve and ground connected to it or taken from it.  It is good practice to have all the separate -ves connected at a single point to avoid "ground loops" - but that's another issue.